# Defining custom command in nvim.init

Tags: linux, vim, vimrc

I am trying to define my custom command in `nvim.init` (NeoVim) but I've occurred an error. Could be so kind and help me with getting rid of it?

Here is a line which I've putted into `nvim.init`:

`commmand GenerateTags find . -type f -iregex ".*\.js$" -not -path "./node_modules/*" -exec jsctags {} -f \; | sed '/^$/d' | sort > tags`

> Error message: E492: Not an editor command: commmand GenerateTags find
>   . -type f -iregex ".*.js$" -not -path "./node_modules/*" -exec
>   jsctags {} -f \; | sed '/^$/d' | sort > tags Press ENTER or type
>   command to continue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the problem was in spelling:
There should be:

- `command` no `commmand`
- `!` before find, because it is a shell command, not a Vim one

Because the task is blocking I found that it would be way better to use a plugin which makes the command [async.](https://github.com/skywind3000/asyncrun.vim)

Here is how the command looks now:

`command GenerateTags AsyncRun find . -type f -iregex ".*\.js$" -not -path "./node_modules/*" -exec jsctags {} -f \; | sed '/^$/d' | sort > tags`